# Find $f '(0)$ if $f(x)= \frac{(x^2+1)(x+1)\cos x}{e^{x(x+3)}}$

Tags: derivatives

I know that to find the derivative, I have to use the product and quotient rule. But I am confused as to how to go about doing it. Thanks!

Comment: Hint:Let $g_1(x)=\frac{(x^2+1)(x+1)}{e^{x(x+3)}}$. Then $f'(0)=g_1'(0)$ by product rule (why?)

Let $g_2(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{e^{x(x+3)}}$. Then $g_1'(0)=g_2'(0)$ by product rule (why?)

Let $g_3(x)=\frac{1}{e^{x(x+3)}}$. Then $g_2'(0)=g_3'(0)$ by prodct rule (why?) 

Finally, you can evaluate the derivative of $\frac{1}{e^{x(x+3)}}=e^{-x(x+3)}$ at zero to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=\dfrac{(x^2+1)(x+1)(\cos x)}{e^{x(x+3)}}$$
Observe that overall $f$ is a quotient, so we must first apply the quotient rule:
$$\left(\dfrac{u}{v}\right)'=\dfrac{u'\cdot v-v'\cdot u}{v^2}.$$
According to our function, we let $u=(x^3+x^2+x+1)(\cos x)$ and $v=e^{x^2+3x}$. Notice we rewrote both expressions so that we don't have to apply the product rule so many times.

All that's needed now to find the derivative $f'(x)$ is to compute $u'$ and $v'$ and then substitute appropriately into the above formula. Of course, use product rule for $u'$ and chain rule for $v'$.

Comment: Long task, don't you think ? Logarithmic differentiation (as answered by StatGod) will make it much faster.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici If the OP is comfortable with logarithmic reduction and implicit differentiation, then all power to him/her. The preference simply depends on the OP's level and what they've been taught so far. I know there are more efficient methods, but for pedagogical reasons I defer to the basic grind.

Comment: I am more comfortable with Brody's suggestion due to my familiarity compared to using logarithmic reduction. Thanks to all for the help! :)

Comment: @mathenator2015 No problem :) Let us know if you need help or clarification with any particular steps. Either way, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $\log$ on both sides first, then take derivatives on both sides. The expression becomes much easier to evaluated.